# How to adjust text in table in latex

Tags: latex, alignment, tabular

I have table with 5 cells ,

I want to let all cells text in the same [adjust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uPCZ.jpg)
my first cell text from four litters and the second cell text is word from 7 litters so the two cells are not in the same adjust

[image]

I  attached picture to show you my problem 
any help please.

Comment: Maybe you can use the `l` alignment in your tabular environment, but without a [mcve] nobody can help you.

Comment: it is working  correctly with me . could you comment it as answer to mark it , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array columns in a tabular environment must be associated with an alignment qualifier. In your example, you probably used `c` (center), but you should have used `l` to have the text in the cells *left* aligned or `r` for a *right* alignment.

But this is very basic LaTeX use and you should absolutely read a [tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) on LaTeX tables.

Note that there are *many* useful packages that extend the tabular functionality and allows to have centered paragraph, to control their vertical alignment, to align digital numbers and so on. Look at [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12672/which-tabular-packages-do-which-tasks-and-which-packages-conflict/12673#12673) in tex.stackexchange.com to have a good overview on existing packages for table formatting.